# how to monitor a folder in windows a run a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I was following this [SO answer](https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created) to monitor a folder , but it is working one time. I mean if create a folder or file the batchfile will run , I created again a folder or edite it , it wont trigger

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\uuu\Desktop\new folder\tttt"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "D:\Copyof\PSlog.txt" -value $logline
                cmd.exe /k "D:\Copyof\move.bat"
              }

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 1}
```

Comment: Don't use these alot but we cant see `move.bat` so something could be locked there possibly. If you remove that line does pslog.txt update? Not sure if you need to remove the old event watchers before changes take effect.

Comment: @Matt yes when I did remove the batch file it worked normally again , not sure what its making locked in the batchfile , because if I run the bach manually it works normally. I cannot show the full move.bat here because its long. do you have any idea how to stop locking it ? a batch file command or something ?

Comment: Isn't the problem coming from your "/k" flag on cmd.exe? It means execute the command and remain.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Oh how did I miss that.  `/K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables`

Comment: @DavidBrabant so the /k is the mistake .. with what should I replace it

Comment: Use a `/C` instead.

Comment: @Moudiz, you can get help for any batch file command you are trying to run by typing the command name followed by a slash and a question mark. ex: `cmd /?`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210568/bat-file-how-to-start-a-bat-file-when-i-rename-any-file-in-a-specific-folder/41214708#41214708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just so this gets an official answer:

> Isn't the problem coming from your "/k" flag on cmd.exe? It means execute the command and remain. – [David Brabant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311712/david-brabant)
>
> /K Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt. This is useful for testing, to examine variables – [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt)
>
> Use a /C instead. – [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark)